# Scale, rotate, drag image using gestures in Android

Tags: android, image, bitmap, draw

I'm building a simple image editing app where user start with a canvas, and he can add new images to the canvas, every time he selects an image to add, he first scale, rotate and move the image to the position he wants it to be, after that the image merges into the canvas.

I've been trying to find tutorials about this but so far I only find how to programmatically do these operations but not dynamically with user's gesture. 
Please help. Thanks in advance!

[image]